# Concurrency Issue with Row Locking and Updating in PostgreSQL Using Python

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, locking, psycopg2

I'm encountering a problem with a Python function designed to update rows in a PostgreSQL database in a highly concurrent environment. The function aims to lock the oldest unassigned row in the realms table using FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED, update it, and commit the transaction. However, I've noticed that when running about 50 requests concurrently, the number of rows updated in the database is less than the total number of function executions. I have verified that the function is executed successfully every time without any issues.

I'm using `psycopg2` to interact with the Postgres Database

```
def allocate_realm(self):
    try:
        with self.db_conn.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("""
                SELECT * FROM realms
                WHERE is_assigned IS NULL
                LIMIT 1
                FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
            """)
            realm = cursor.fetchone()

            if realm:
                cursor.execute("UPDATE realms SET is_assigned = 'some_value' WHERE id = %s;", (realm[0],))
                self.db_conn.commit()
            else:
                # Handle the case when no unassigned realm is found
                pass
    except Exception:
        self.db_conn.rollback()
        # Error handling
```

**Concurrency**: Around 50 concurrent requests

What could be causing the discrepancy in the number of rows updated versus the total number of function executions in this concurrent setup? Are there any improvements needed in the way I'm handling transactions or locks to ensure an accurate reflection of updates in the database?

Meanwhile, I checked even for 5 parallel requests which failed similarly.

Comment: [For Update](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE): *With SKIP LOCKED, any selected rows that cannot be immediately locked are skipped.*

Comment: [FOR UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE): *Similarly, if a locking clause is used in a cursor's query, only rows actually fetched or stepped past by the cursor will be locked* => what happens if you use a normal select query instead of cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by making use of a sub-query within an UPDATE query rather than fetching and updating in 2 different queries within the same transaction. Here's my query as follows -

```
UPDATE realms SET is_assigned = 'some_value'
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM realms
    WHERE is_assigned IS NULL
    LIMIT 1
    FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
)
RETURNING *;
```

After updating the query, I tested it with more than 1000 parallel requests using JMeter and this worked like a charm without much/any performance impact. I'm still confused why this works and others failed. Although one explanation I couldn't come up with a reasonable solution for why my original query didn't work.

Comment: does it work if you still use 2 different queries but get rid of cursor?

Comment: I haven't tried that one yet.

Comment: I was doubting that cursor was the root cause of the problem